# SQL command is executing but is returning false in the mysqli connection

Tags: php, mysql

I have a web page created in php using html code. I want to save user information entered in my web page to a MySQL database. I am using php as the middle man to link the frontend web page(htmnl code) to the database(mysql).

Inside my link folder (middle man php file) I have the following:

```
<?php
//Gets server connection credentials stored in serConCred2.php
require_once('ConCred2.php');

//SQL code for connection w/ error control
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if(!$con){
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
//Selection of the databse w/ error control
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($con, DB_NAME);

if(!$db_selected){
die('Can not use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysqli_error($con));
}


//Co-PI and Co-Investigator Information variables
$Co_FNAME = $_POST['fname'];
$Co_LNAME = $_POST['lname'];
$Co_SLNAME = $_POST['slname'];
$Co_DEGREE = $_POST['Degree_Selection'];
$Co_DEGREE_Other = $_POST['other_specify_degree']; //hold the value of degree if user selected other from the dropdown menu
$Co_CPOS = $_POST['Current_Position_Selection'];
$Co_CPOS_Other = $_POST['other_specify_cpos']; //hold the value of Current Position if user selected other from the dropdown menu
$Co_INST = $_POST['Institution_Selection'];
$Co_INST_Other = $_POST['other_specify_inst']; //hold the value of Current Position if user selected other from the dropdown menu
$Co_SCHOOL = $_POST['School_Selection'];
$Co_SCHOOL_Other = $_POST['other_specify_school']; //hold the value of Current Position if user selected other from the dropdown menu
$Co_DEPART = $_POST['Department_Selection']; //Este se estara eliminando en la version online
$Co_DEPART_Other = $_POST['other_specify_department']; //hold the value of Department if user selected other from the dropdown menu
$Co_PROGRAM = $_POST['program'];
$Co_EMAIL = $_POST['email'];
$Co_PHONE = $_POST['phone'];


//If decition when user select other from the dropdown menu
if($Co_DEGREE == "other_degree") $Co_DEGREE = $Co_DEGREE_Other;
if($Co_CPOS == "other_cpos") $Co_CPOS = $Co_CPOS_Other;
if($Co_INST == "other_inst") $Co_INST = $Co_INST_Other;
if($Co_SCHOOL == "other_school") $Co_SCHOOL = $Co_SCHOOL_Other;
if($Co_DEPART_Other == "other_department") $Co_DEPART = $Co_DEPART_Other;

//This sets a starting point in the rollback process in case of errors along the code
$success = true; //Flag to determine success of transaction
//start transaction
echo "<br>1. Going to set autocommit to 0";
$command = "SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0";
echo "<br>2. Autocomint has been set to 0";

echo "<br>3. Going to run query to see if result is true or false";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $command);
echo "<br>4. Finished running the query. Result is:" . $result;

echo "<br>5. Going to set command to BEGIN";
$command = "BEGIN";
echo "<br>6. Command is now BEGIN";

echo "<br>7. Going to run query for command BEGIN";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $command);
echo "<br>8. Query runned for command BEGIN";

echo "<br>9. Result value is: " . $result;
//Saves Pi values into database
/**
$sqlCoPI = "INSERT INTO co_pi_table (Fname, Lname, SLname, Degree, Current_Position, Institution, School, Department, Program, Email, Phone)
                        VALUES('$Co_FNAME', '$Co_LNAME', '$Co_SLNAME', '$Co_DEGREE', '$Co_CPOS', '$Co_INST', '$Co_SCHOOL', '$Co_DEPART', '$Co_PROGRAM', '$Co_EMAIL', '$Co_PHONE')";
*/


echo "<br>10. Going to write sql command to populate table pi_table";
/**
$sqlPi = "INSERT INTO pi_table (Fname, Lname, SLname, Degree, Current_Position, Institution, School, Department, Program, Email, Phone)
                        VALUES('$Co_FNAME', '$Co_LNAME', '$Co_SLNAME', '$Co_DEGREE', '$Co_CPOS', '$Co_INST', '$Co_SCHOOL', '$Co_DEPART', '$Co_PROGRAM', '$Co_EMAIL', '$Co_PHONE')";                 
*/

$sqlPi = "INSERT INTO pi_table (Fname) VALUES('$Co_FNAME')";                    


                        //Checks to see if theres an error in the pi db con
echo "<br>11. Sql command finished writting.";  

echo "<br>12. Going to query the sql finished command to the database to determine value of result.";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sqlPi);
echo "<br>13. Finished running sql command to database. Result value is: " . $result;   

echo "<br>14. Going to enter if statements depending on result value";
    if($result == false){
    //die ('<br>Error in query to PI table: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    echo "<br>15. I am inside the false statement. Success is going to be set as false. ";
    $success = false;
    //$success = true; //Cahnged this in order to test if values are being saved to db. Change back to false.
}

 //Checks for errors or craches inside the code
 // If found, execute rollback

 echo "<br>16. Going to verify is success is true.";
 if($success){
     $command = "COMMIT";
     $result = mysqli_query($con, $command);
     //echo "<br>Tables have been saved with 0 errors.";
     echo "<br><p style=\"color: red;\"Principal Investigator has been saved successfuly. <br><br>
     You may now CLOSE this page and press the<br><br> \"Refresh List\" <br><br>
     button to display name in dropdown menu selection.</p>";
 }
 else{
     $command = "ROLLBACK";
     $result = mysqli_query($con, $command);

     echo "<br>17. Success was determined to be false.";
     echo "<br>Error! Databases could not be saved.<br>
     Contact system manager to report error. <br> <br>" . mysqli_error($con);
 }

 echo "<br>18. Setting autocommit back to 1 again.";
 $command = "SET AUTOCOMMIT = 1"; //return to autocommit
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $command);


//Displays message 
//echo '<br>Connection Successfully. ';
//echo '<br>Database have been saved';

//Close the sql connection to dababase
mysqli_close($con)                      

?>
```

As you can read, I am requiring users to fill out their information. Some of the information required are dropdown menu fields that user selects an option from among the presented ones.

The problem I am having is, when the above php code executes, it determines that the $result variable is false and doesn't save anything. When you execute the code, you get the following messages displayed:

```
1. Going to set autocommit to 0
2. Autocomint has been set to 0
3. Going to run query to see if result is true or false
4. Finished running the query. Result is:1
5. Going to set command to BEGIN
6. Command is now BEGIN
7. Going to run query for command BEGIN
8. Query runned for command BEGIN
9. Result value is: 1
10. Going to write sql command to populate table pi_table
11. Sql command finished writting.
12. Going to query the sql finished command to the database to determine value of result.
13. Finished running sql command to database. Result value is: 
14. Going to enter if statements depending on result value
15. I am inside the false statement. Success is going to be set as false. 
16. Going to verify is success is true.
17. Success was determined to be false.
Error! Databases could not be saved.
 Contact system manager to report error. 


18. Setting autocommit back to 1 again.
```

For security purposes I cant post the html content since it has sensitive name information nor the databases. Although I can ensure that the tables inside the database are called exactly as mentioned in the sql command line.

Comment: Have you checked [mysqli_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)?

Comment: I have. But it doesn't display the error message. It appears blank.

Comment: Can you show where/how you're using it?  If `mysqli_query()` returns `false`, then you should get something from `mysqli_error()`.

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and 
 other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: you can test inside phpmyadmin, check the table then you can query to select something

Comment: I tested your current code, after I replaced all `$_POST[''xyz]` assignments with simple strings and all worked fine. `$result` is always `true`, `$success` is also `true`.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @tadman lucky for PHP devs "bobby tables" most likely will not be exploited on PHP. Because most PHP MySQL API's functions does not support multiple queries separated with semicon unless you are using `mysqli_multi_query`  But you are right the query still needs to protected against other more severe SQL injections.

Comment: @RaymondNijland `mysqli_multi_query` should be hurled into the sun and expunged from PHP permanently, but it's still used to a worrying degree.That `DROP TABLES` example is also the most egregious, SQL injection is often far more subtle and way more dangerous than that. Parameters *must* be escaped, and the easiest, most reliable way to do that is prepared statements with placeholder values.

Comment: I upvoted this question for taking the time to do some diagnostics and include the results of your testing.

Comment: "but it's still used to a worrying degree" @tadman how do you know? you don't have access to everybodys PHP code on this planet. You are just plain guessing there in mine opinion.. But i agree to the prepared statements don't get me wrong.. (this is for the topicstarter) In fact every query to the database should be protected with prepared statements **no exceptions** not even when you think the variable is "safe" like working with the $_SESSION array

Comment: @tadman what to do, if you need to substitute a table name?

Comment: @zen You do that very, very, *very* carefully, usually by checking that the name exists in a very strict white-list of allowed values and even then by *never* using the `$_POST` value directly to ensure that a simple mistake that removes the check doesn't create a huge vulnerability. Consider user data "tainted" and never let come into contact with a query string. Engineer to "fail safe" (crash) instead of "fail dangerous" (SQL injection hole).

Comment: @RaymondNijland Using it even one time is too many, and I've seen it used hundreds of times in the last five years on Stack Overflow questions alone. This doesn't include PHP-based projects I've had to audit, review, or have "inherited".

Comment: @tadman Thank you for the recommendations on sql injection bug. I will fix this newbie mistake of mine.

Comment: Also, THANK YOU everyone for your support! I am so greatful! Tadman, @RaymondNijland

Answer (score 1):

I HAVE FOUND THE PROBLEM!

After long debating I decided to recreate the database In which all the information was being stored. When I redirected the table in my sql command ( Instead of saving it in "pi_table" I saved it in a newly created database called "pi_table_2") and everything worked out properly.

Aparently my database got corrupted and phpMyAdmin didn't recognized that it was curropted.

For reference my database tables where in InnoDB format. What might have cause this to happen, who knows but if you ever encounter a similar problem, creating a small testing database and see if it saves. If it does, recreate the table and it might solve your issue like it solved mine.

Once again thank you a lot guys!!!!!

Comment: Good job in tracking down the issue and fixing it.

Answer (score -2):

I am looking at the code and everything seems to be in order, could be a syntax error like a missing quotation for example:

```
//SQL code for connection w/ error control
$con = mysqli_connect("DB_HOST", "DB_USER", "DB_PASSWORD", "DB_NAME");
```

also

```
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($con, "DB_NAME");
or die ("Cant select Database");
}
```

Hope this help.
Cheers;
Hasan

Comment: `DB_HOST` etc are likely [constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) set in ConCred2.php

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to solve any problems and focuses on a part of the question that's likely not the source of the issues.

Comment: One advice you if willing to answer on questions in the future. Read the question properly it might save you some downvotes in the future... Because a PHP syntax error would cause PHP to stop execution and display a error or a "white screen of death" and display a error the topicstarter clearly says in the question he is getting debugging information